# Internal app sharing show downloading error | Error retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01

Tags: android, internal-app-sharing

I published my app in internal app sharing. After I shared link to download to myself, but to another account. I turn on internal app sharing in Google Play on my phone. When I click downloading, I catch error -> Error retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01

[image]I tried to test in two phones, but with same google account.

Comment: I have the same problem , do you found any solution ?

Comment: after few hours it started to work, but before this I published my app in google play, Maybe publishing my app helped.

Comment: Also worked for me after some hours , witthout publishing. So may answer your question as it take some time

Comment: I have same problem, went 24 hour but same error is appearing, also tried to remove cache & data but same error is displaying every time

Comment: Notice that this is the same error that you get if an app with the same package name is already installed on that device. I looked in logcat and found this: `I/Finsky: [22634] kqp.run(25): Dropped referrer for com.bar.foo because dropped_already_installed`. Tried to uninstall, click the share link again and then the error disappeared.

Answer (score 23):

There is a step I missed - testers have to opt in to the test program before they can use the shared link, and until they do they get the opaque DF-DFERH-01 error. On the Play Console under Release Management, select App releases. In Internal test track, click Manage. Under Manage Testers click the drop arrow. This opens up a panel, and near the bottom is an opt-in URL. Copy this and send it to testers. They have to click on this link and agree to opt in to the test program. They can then download the current version. After this they can also use internal app sharing links for new builds.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! Such an unintuitive process.

Comment: I've reported this issue to Android Play Console support. Don't know if they will fix it. In their first response I was given a link to a help page on how to set up internal app sharing, which didn't mention the Opt-in URL step.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me. I had created a new app listing and facing this issue. I wished google would have thrown more meaningful error messages rather than the same obscure error code for bunch of different scenarios.

Comment: This is a very bad experience, caused by a poor error message. I faced a similar problem when I hadn't checked the list of testers. Clicking an internal app link resulted in a black screen and spinning wheel. I've lost a lot of hours on this broken UX.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to access the internally shared debug app not a production testing app.  For this, I was using `Internal App Sharing` feature. To be able to install and use such apps one's email needs to be added to an email-list(as per the settings we had) otherwise, anyone with the link can install.
[image]

### Problem

The problem is despite having my email in the list, and email representing a google account I was not able to install it. I faced this error.
[Click here to see the Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXTlH.png)

### Cause

I maintain about 8 google accounts on my mobile and I was logged in to all of them. I realized having multiple accounts is causing the issue.

### Solution

Instead of logging out from all the google accounts, I simply created a new user in my mobile and set it up. Then I opted-in to `Internal App Sharing` in the App store. Then shared the app link via google-keep. Voila, I was able to install it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just had to wait ~48 hours and it Just Worked with no other changes.

Answer (score 0):

A few more silly things to consider if you are new to Google Play Console.

1. You need to make sure to enable **Internal App Sharing** on Google Play Settings, [here](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-store-developer-setting-enable-internal-app-sharing/#:%7E:text=Simply%20open%20up%20the%20Play,pop%20up%20on%20your%20device.) is a tutorial for that.
2. Do not forget to publish your modifications by clicking on **publication overview** (sorry for the Portuguese language on the pic, but you can find through the icon):

[image: publication overview]

And then publishing it by clicking on the blue button (**publish modifications or something like that**):

[image: publish button]

3. After doing this, try to clean the cache of your play store and remove all updates from play store (after doing this you'll need to enable **Internal App Sharing** again).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of the error by clearing the storage of the google play store app then open the play store app again and enabling the internal app feature then opening the internal app sharing link again.

sometimes if that didn't work , restarting the device does the trick!